# QGIS Forms - How Do I Display a Read-Only Value?

Tags: qgis, spatial-database, editing

Older versions of QGIS had an "Immutable" option for form fields to make it obvious that data was read-only.  How do I display values in the current version and make it obvious that they are read-only?  (Useful for showing auto IDs etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has now been fixed in QGIS 2.6.  Non-editable widgets are now greyed-out.

Answer (score 1):

If you go into layer properties, then go to the "**Fields**" section, then click on the "**Edit Widget**" option, [image]

You get a checkable option to make the form field editable. Uncheck that box and that should be it.

Comment: Unfortunately, setting a field to "read-only" doesn't change the style of the widget.  It still looks like an editable item to the user and it still has an "erase" button on the right which appears to wipe the value.  The old immutable option greyed-out or disabled the widget which was a better solution.